# Change status bar background color in some view controllers - Swift

Tags: swift

I am building a iOS app in Swift and I need to change the background color of the status bar in some view controllers. I have been able to change the text color however I am not able to find a way to change the background.

I am allowing "View controller-based status bar appearance" to YES and using

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .LightContent
```

in the viewDidLoad method.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each view controller will use a `preferredStatusBarStyle` rather than on the application

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/preferredStatusBarStyle

Comment: Thanks. I have the text changing color but not sure how to change the bar background color. Not sure how to implement this in the view controller.

Comment: The docs link shows it. Literally, you add a preferredStausBarStyle method to your viewController subclass and return the appropriate constant for the style you want. This is the proper way of changing the status bar. If you're trying to do something extra-odd, then this approach won't work, no.